# Rust developing on gas pipes inside furnace under the intake pipe. Need help figuiring out why it is happening and how to fix it. Thanks

Tags: furnace, rust

The rust that has developed on the gas pipes from condensation coming from air intake above the furnace.  [image: The rust that has developed is directly under the air intake for the furnace- not sure if the air coming in has some condensation happening and causing the damage]